# Integer programming: Is it possible to define an incompatibility constraint?

Tags: integer-programming, operations-research

I'm using [jsLPSolver](https://github.com/JWally/jsLPSolver) to solve an integer-programming problem.

I'm having trouble adjusting the model to contain incompatibility constraints.
I've got the following model:

```
{
    "optimize": "cost",
    "opType": "min",
    "constraints": {
        "c1": { "min": 36000.0, "max": 36800.0 },
        "c2": { "min": 12000.0, "max": 12800.0 },
        "c3": { "equal": 1000.0 }
    },
    "variables": {
        "p1": { "c1": 0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 437.47, },
        "p2": { "c1": 0, "c2": 60.0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1964.49, },
        "p3": { "c1": 34.0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1428.98, },
        "p4": { "c1": 46.0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1973.11, }
    },
    "ints": { "p1": 1, "p2": 1, "p3": 1, "p4": 1 }
}
```

and the *feasible* result

```
{ bounded: true, feasible: true, p2: 200, p3: 66, p4: 734, result: 1935473.42 }
```

However, it exists a constraint that `p3` and `p4` **could not be together** in the solution, because they are incompatible.

Is it possible to define an incompatibility constraint to define that `p3` and `p4` is incompatible variables?

**EDIT**

I'm thinking about use a constraint like `p3 + p4 = 0`:

```
{
    "optimize": "cost",
    "opType": "min",
    "constraints": {
        "c1": { "min": 36000.0, "max": 36800.0 },
        "c2": { "min": 12000.0, "max": 12800.0 },
        "c3": { "equal": 1000.0 },
        "incompatible": { "equal": 0.0 }
    },
    "variables": {
        "p1": { "c1": 0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 437.47, "incompatible": 0.0 },
        "p2": { "c1": 0, "c2": 60.0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1964.49, "incompatible": 0.0 },
        "p3": { "c1": 34.0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1428.98, "incompatible": 1.0 },
        "p4": { "c1": 46.0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1973.11, "incompatible": 1.0 }
    },
    "ints": { "p1": 1, "p2": 1, "p3": 1, "p4": 1 }
}
```

but see what happens to the solution in this case:

```
{ bounded: true, feasible: false, p2: 200, p3: -3000, p4: 3000, result: 0 }
```

as seen on https://runkit.com/tetrimesquita/incompatible-contraint, which is *correct* but *unfeasible*.

Comment: What does incompatible mean? Only one of the variables can be nonzero?

Comment: @Dion, yes... If one is nonzero, another has to be zero.

Comment: Why not use `p3 * p4 = 0` then?

Comment: Alternatively, you could solve your system twice - once without `p3`, and once without `p4`, then take the solution with the lower cost.

Comment: I'll try `p3 * p4 = 0`, teorically it should work... if works, I'll ask you to answer and you can win 200 reputation bounty ;)

Comment: I had a closer look at `jsLPSolver`, and realized it is a *linear* solver. So you probably can't specify `p3 * p4 = 0`, since that would be a non-linear constraint. But you can always try my second idea.

Answer (score 1):

I see now that `p3` and `p4` are continuous. (If they are actually binary, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56113218/3453768).) In that case, add two new binary variables, say `z3` and `z4`, that equal 1 if `p3` and `p4` (respectively) are greater than zero:

```
p3 <= Mz3
p4 <= Mz4
```

where `M` is a large number. Then add a constraint

```
z3 + z4 <= 1
```

The first two constraints say that if `p3 > 0`, then `z3` must equal `1` (and similarly for `p4` and `z4`). The third constraint says at most one of `z3` and `z4` can equal 1, i.e., at most one of `p3` and `p4` can be positive.

If `p3` and `p4` are unrestricted (allowed to be positive or negative) and you want to require at most one of them to be *nonzero*, then also add:

```
-p3 <= Mz3
-p4 <= Mz4
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant version out there, but this should do it:

```js
var solver = require("javascript-lp-solver");

var model = {
    "optimize": "cost",
    "opType": "min",
    "constraints": {
        "c1": { "min": 36000.0, "max": 36800.0 },
        "c2": { "min": 12000.0, "max": 12800.0 },
        "c3": { "equal": 1000.0 }
    },
    "variables": {
        "p1": { "c1": 0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 437.47, },
        "p2": { "c1": 0, "c2": 60.0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1964.49, },
        "p3": { "c1": 34.0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1428.98, },
    },
    "ints": { "p1": 1, "p2": 1, "p3": 1}
}

var results_p3 = solver.Solve(model);

var model = {
    "optimize": "cost",
    "opType": "min",
    "constraints": {
        "c1": { "min": 36000.0, "max": 36800.0 },
        "c2": { "min": 12000.0, "max": 12800.0 },
        "c3": { "equal": 1000.0 }
    },
    "variables": {
        "p1": { "c1": 0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 437.47, },
        "p2": { "c1": 0, "c2": 60.0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1964.49, },
        "p4": { "c1": 46.0, "c2": 0, "c3": 1, "cost": 1973.11, }
    },
    "ints": { "p1": 1, "p2": 1, "p4": 1 }
}

var results_p4 = solver.Solve(model);

var finalResults = (results_p3.feasible && (results_p3.result < results_p4.result)) ? results_p3 : results_p4;

console.log(results_p3);
console.log(results_p4);
console.log(finalResults);
```

The idea is that you run the model twice - once where `p3` is fixed, and once where `p4` is fixed. Then you take the solution that obeys the constraints and yields the better result [1].

See output here:

https://runkit.com/dionhaefner/so-incompatible-constraint

[1] You should probably polish that last check a little. E.g., what should happen if both results are infeasible? What if both have a result of 0? You might have to check the `bounded` property, too.

Answer (score 0):

If `p3` and `p4` are binary, you can just use

```
p3 + p4 <= 1
```

Or if you want *exactly* one of them to equal 1, then use

```
p3 + p4 = 1
```

I'm not familiar with the syntax for jsLPSolver, but the constraints above provide the logic.